# Ad-blocker for my home network

Tags: gratis, website-blocker, ad-blocker

I'm looking for an ad-blocker that protects all hosts in my private home network, even guests that temporarily connect via WLAN.

I have Windows and Linux machines as well as Android phones, but there might be guests using Apple hardware. It should still work for all of them.

The solution must

- be free of cost
- work for all devices / all platforms
- ideally be open source
- simple and easy to use

If there's additional hardware cost involved, that's ok for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found that [Pi-Hole](https://pi-hole.net/) suits my needs.

- It's gratis
- It's open source
- it supports all hardware and platforms, because it blocks ads on DNS level.
- simple and easy to use: the clients do not need to install any software. They will be configured via DHCP automatically.

Hardware cost: 1 Raspberry Pi 1A, 1 SD card (4 GB is enough), 1 power supply. Total less than 50 €.

Installation: almost as simple as described on the website (I had to perform an `apt-get update`, `apt-get upgrade` and `reboot` before).

Configuration: you have to set up the DHCP of your Internet router (DSL router) to provide the Raspberry Pi's address as the DNS server.

Comment: Hadn't you already self-answered … That's about what works for me satisfactorily more than 2 years already – with the exception of using a BananaPi and the [Unbound](http://www.unbound.net/) nameserver. Same principle :)

Comment: There has been a problem with windows 10 update being blocked by the pi-hole. It will work eventually, but it will take a long time.

Comment: @Blake: thanks for the information. I'll deactivate for some minutes and check for updates.